# Changing color of single character in StaticText

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I am writing a program that randomly generates encrypted quotations from famous people. My program displays a cryptoquote and the user must decode the quote. I want to take input from on which letter to decode. I've successfully implemented it such that, when they specify a letter to decode (example:"a=e"), the program replaces the encrypted text with the text that they specified.

I want it so that, when a letter is replaced, it is colored red so that the user can keep up with what letters they have changed.

```
def OnDec(self, e):
        dlg = wx.TextEntryDialog(self, "Which letter do you wish to change? Use format: 'a=e'", "Decode Letter", "")
        dlg.ShowModal()
        decode = dlg.GetValue()
        #Text entry filter
        match = re.search(r'\w+=\w+|^\d*$', decode)
        if not match:
            err = wx.MessageDialog(self, "That is not a correct entry format.", "Entry Error", style=wx.ICON_HAND)
            err.ShowModal()
        #Letter replacement
        origin = decode[0].upper()
        replace = decode[2].upper()
        for n in range(0, len(cryp)):
            if cryp[n] == origin:
                cryp[n] = replace
        self.txt.SetLabel("".join(cryp))
        self.txt.SetForegroundColour("RED")
        self.sizer.Layout()
```

This procedure is the event that executes when the "Decode Letter" button is pressed. `cryp` here is a list of each individual letter that I made from the encrypted quotations. The requested format for the `decode` variable is "a=b".

I can change the whole `label` to RED, but I want to just change the color of the letters that have been decoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StaticText widget does not support that behavior. You can probably do that with a read-only wx.TextCtrl that has the wx.TE_RICH or wx.TE_RICH2 flag enabled. Otherwise you might just want to draw the text using wx.GCDC or wx.PaintDC. That would be even more flexible.